# Issues using skopeo copy to gcr, unable to authenticate on google cloud

Tags: docker, containers, google-container-registry, skopeo

I'm trying to pull and push images in a Gitlab pipeline avoiding to use docker-in-docker approach so I'm trying to use skopeo for that.

But right now I'm having issues authenticating skopeo on gcr because we use key authentication for Service Accounts, that doesn't seems to be supported (at least I couldn't make it work) by skopeo, and we don't want to use user and password for that.

The error message is this one:

```
unable to retrieve auth token: invalid username/password: unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication
```

What are the possibilities I can explore to make authentication work?

Answer (score 2):

I just found a way to solve that authentication issue, we must use `--dest-registry-token` flag like this:

```
skopeo copy --dest-registry-token "$(gcloud auth print-access-token)" docker://nginx:1.23.1 docker://us.gcr.io/project/nginx:1.23.1
```

And make sure that before doing that you activate the Service Account.

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file $SOME_FILE
```